# No border for widgets when porting from Qt 5.2 to Qt 5.3

Tags: qt, stylesheet, qgraphicsview

I have a project in Qt. It contains few graphics view,buttons, frames and labels. In Qt 5.2 all these used to have a white border around them at run time. However now I have migrated to Qt 5.3 and these borders are not visible. I tried setting the style sheet by using setStyleSheet("border-color:rgb..") but still the white border around any of the objects is not visible.

Has Qt changed anything in this aspect?

Thank You.

Comment: How about `setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid white;");`, does that work?

Comment: I tried that. The problem is there are some items in the grid on that frame. They also get that white border. I only want the outer boundary of the frame to get the color.

Comment: Use a [selector](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types) then: `setStyleSheet(".QFrame{border: 2px solid white;}");`

Comment: Ok I will try this and tell.

Comment: No this also is not working. Same problem. In Qt 5.2 I never had to handle this. I had made the entire window background black with rgb:38,38,38 and the outer frames and labels had taken the white boundary. I am not getting the same effect for Qt 5.3

Comment: So the items inside the frame are frames as well. Then use an ID selector: `setStyleSheet("QFrame#myFrame{border: 2px solid white;}");` To make this work you must set an [object name](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#objectName-prop) to your frame (i assumed it's *myFrame* in the code snippet). How did you set the white borders for your frames back in 5.2 when it worked?

Comment: I didn't set them at all. I even tried with a small project in Qt 5.2. It seems when the background is black the frames and labels themselves take the white border. I will try what you have suggested.

Comment: The solution that you said has worked. Now only that required frame is taking the white border. But I am still wondering why it is required to be handled in Qt 5.3 and not in 5.2. Thanks for your help. You mention it in the answer I will mark it helpful. Thanks again :)

Comment: That is strange. I cannot replicate that. You must always specify [frame shape](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qframe.html#Shape-enum) to get a frame drawn.

Comment: Set the frame boundary as styledPanel and raised. Does it work that way?

Comment: Yes, but then it works both on 5.2 and 5.3.

Comment: Oh is it. I tried with a small project too still not helping. Anyways thanks for the help.

Comment: Hey that problem is with the version. I reverted back to the old version and its working fine. In fact even the tables and tab widgets were not having the top header as white. I will try testing this on the some different machine but as of now I will go with the old version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a style sheet and specify a [selector](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types) to apply a border to specific items.

ID selector:

```
setStyleSheet("QFrame#myFrame{border: 2px solid white;}");
```

To make this work you must set an [object name](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#objectName-prop) to your object. This assumes that the object's name is *myFrame*.

Class selector:

```
setStyleSheet(".QFrame{border: 2px solid white;}");
```